# How to initialize a dictionary from String and String?

Tags: swift, dictionary, initialization

My specific task is to create a failable initializer that accepts a dictionary as the parameter and initializes all stored properties of the struct. The keys should be "title", "author", "price" and "pubDate".

```
struct Book {
    let title: String
    let author: String
    let price: String?
    let pubDate: String?
```

I'm just not sure what to do here. I've gone down a few different routes and read the documentation on dictionaries and initializers without any luck. I'm mostly unsure how to set up the parameter for the init method. This is (abstract) idea I have

```
init?([dict: ["title": String], ["author": String], ["price": String], ["pubDate": String]]) {
        self.title = dict["title"]
        self.author = dict["author"]
        self.price = dict["price"]
        self.pubDate = dict["pubDate"]
    }
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Use `dict: [String:String]` as the parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
struct Book {
    let title: String
    let author: String
    let price: String?
    let pubDate: String?

    init?(dict: [String: String]) {
        guard dict["title"] != nil && dict["author"] != nil else {
            // A book must have title and author. If not, fail by returning nil
            return nil
        }

        self.title = dict["title"]!
        self.author = dict["author"]!
        self.price = dict["price"]
        self.pubDate = dict["pubDate"]
    }
}

// Usage:
let book1 = Book(dict: ["title": "Harry Potter", "author": "JK Rowling"])
let book2 = Book(dict: ["title": "Harry Potter", "author": "JK Rowling", "price": "$25"])
let book3 = Book(dict: ["title": "A book with no author"]) // nil
```

This says a book must have an `author` and a `title`. If it doesn't have either one, it will fail. `price` and `pubDate` are optional.